# How to get bird view image which is synthized four side images?(get AVM: around view monitoring)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Hi I'm making avm(around view monitoring) image by getting four side images from four fisheye cameras. It's the example image of AVM.

[image]

This process has three parts:

1. calibrate fisheye image/video/streaming
2. get top view(bird view) image
3. get avm image by synthesizing four side images

I has completed 1 and 2 parts, but I'm in trouble doing third part. I researched it and I found that it is may related to 'stitching' or 'numpy array'. But I don't know how to do it although I read documentation.

4 corner overlaps exist(topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright).4 cameras are fixed. I don't know how to synthesize four images, and present result image is below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvzSo.png)

I used np.hstack for stitch three view(leftview, middleview, rightview)
(See birdView)

If you know anythings about it, please comment and share your thoughts.

Thank you for your reading. (I'm using opencv, python, raspberrypi 4B)

code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
from Camera.Undistortion import UndistortFisheye
from Camera.PerspectiveTransformation import EagleView
# from Camera.Stitcher import stitchTwoImages
import time

class avm:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__leftCamera = UndistortFisheye("left_Camera")
        self.__rightCamera = UndistortFisheye("right_Camera")

        self.__leftEagle = EagleView()
        self.__rightEagle = EagleView()
        # self.__frontEagle.setDimensions((149, 195), (439, 207), (528, 380), (37, 374))
        # self.__backEagle.setDimensions((164, 229), (469, 229), (588, 430), (45, 435))
        
        #reset left/right setDimensions
        self.__leftEagle.setDimensions((186, 195), (484, 207), (588, 402), (97, 363))
        self.__rightEagle.setDimensions((171, 240), (469, 240), (603, 452), (52, 441))
        # self.__leftEagle.setDimensions((186, 195), (484, 207), (588, 402), (97, 363))
        # self.__rightEagle.setDimensions((171, 240), (469, 240), (603, 452), (52, 441))

        self.__middleView = None
        self.__counter = 0

        # self.stitcher = stitchTwoImages("Bottom2Upper")
        # self.upper = None
        # self.bottom = None
    
    def runAVM(self, leftFrame, rightFrame):
        leftView = self.__leftCamera.undistort(leftFrame)
        topDown_left = self.__leftEagle.transfrom(leftView)
        rightView = self.__rightCamera.undistort(rightFrame)
        topDown_right = self.__rightEagle.transfrom(rightView)
        # topDown_Back = cv2.flip(topDown_Back, 1) #flip left/right

        topDown_left , topDown_right = self.__reScale(topDown_left, topDown_right)
        # stitchingResult = self.__startStitching(topDown_Front)
        middleView = self.__getMiddleView(topDown_left)
        birdView = np.hstack((topDown_left, middleView, topDown_right))
        return birdView
    
    def __reScale(self, topDown_left, topDown_right):
        width_leftView = topDown_left.shape[1]
        width_rightView = topDown_right.shape[1]
        height_leftView = topDown_left.shape[0]
        height_rightView = topDown_right.shape[0]
        if height_leftView > height_rightView:
            newHeight = height_rightView
            ratio = height_rightView/height_leftView
            newWidth = int(ratio * width_leftView)
            topDown_left = cv2.resize(topDown_left, (newWidth, newHeight))
        else:
            newHeight = height_leftView
            ratio = height_leftView/height_rightView
            newWidth = int(ratio * width_rightView)
            topDown_right = cv2.resize(topDown_right, (newWidth, newHeight))
        
        return topDown_left, topDown_right
    
    def __getMiddleView(self, topDown_left):
        # the length of the image represents the distance in front or back of the car
        width_leftView = topDown_left.shape[1]
        if self.__middleView is None:
            realWidth_leftView = 13 # unit is cm
            realWidth_MiddleView = 29.5 # unit is cm
            ratio = int(width_leftView/realWidth_leftView)
            width_MiddleView = int(realWidth_MiddleView * ratio)
            height_MiddleView = int(topDown_left.shape[0])  
            self.__middleView = np.zeros((height_MiddleView, width_MiddleView//2, 3), np.uint8)
            # print(ratio)
        # else:
        #     #  self.__middleView[0:stitchingResult.shape[0], :]

        return self.__middleView

    # def __startStitching(self, accView):
    #     if self.bottom is None:
    #         self.bottom = accView
    #         return None
    #     else:
    #         # time.sleep(0.5)
    #         self.upper = accView
    #         self.bottom = self.stitcher.stitch(self.bottom, self.upper)
    #         cv2.imshow("Result", self.bottom)
    #         height = accView.shape[0]
    #         return self.bottom[height:self.bottom.shape[0], :]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @gunny. Please read [ask] and update your answer with more details. Your question is not clear here. You mentioned you use `np.hstack` but what is the issue then? Please add the code and the inputs and expected output as images in the question itself so that others can help you better. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your comments. It's first time to question through OS, so I must be unskilled. If there is more comments, please talk to me. Thank you again:)

Comment: what is the shape of each of the images, leftview, righview etc?

Comment: both images are (508, 221) shape.
But I resize result image to (240, 320)

Comment: `(508, 221)` or `(508, 221, 3)` with 3 color channels?

Comment: oh, (508, 221, 3) with 3 color channels.

Comment: what is your question here? are you having trouble creating the stack?

Comment: I want to make avm image synthesized by four side images(it is shown above. First image),
but what I can make is two side images(it is shown above. second image).

Question is how to synthesize four side images to make avm image.

Comment: ah ok, what is the center image, middleview? which position is that taken from? is that the same as topview?

Comment: center image(black image) is np.zeros((_, _, 3), np.uint8).
So, it is shown as black.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `hstack` and `vstack` to get the `awm` view that you are looking for. Just make sure that the individual images are oriented as the below random images I am creating. (Use `np.rot90` if required)

```
#Assume you have 4 views
leftview = np.random.random((508, 221, 3)) #tall image
rightview = np.random.random((508, 221, 3)) #tall image
frontview = np.random.random((221, 508, 3)) #wide image
backview = np.random.random((221, 508, 3)) #wide image

#Creating color differences to view better. 
#IGNORE THIS PART OF CODE
leftview[:,:,0]=1
rightview[:,:,1]=1
frontview[:,:,0:2]=1
backview[:,:,1:3]=1

#Calculate centerview size
width = frontview.shape[1]-(leftview.shape[1]*2)
height = leftview.shape[0]
centerview = np.zeros((height,width,3))

#Hstack the l,c,r views and then Vstack it between the f, b views
lr = np.hstack([leftview,centerview,rightview])
ud = np.vstack([frontview, lr, backview])

#Plot the new image
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,8))
plt.imshow(ud)
```

[image]

Comment: wow. That's what I expected to create.
Thank you a lot!!!

To go a step further, I will input images to random image sites.
If I have any question later, I will contact again.

Comment: sure, glad to help. it this solved your problem then do mark the solution as it encourages me to help you with your future questions :)